# QGIS, SpatiaLite and GPS integration

Tags: qgis, gps, spatialite, integration

I have QGIS an, access database and a Haicom gps all connected and running on a windows 8 machine.

I want to integrate all 3 items so that while in the field i can enter information into the database ie bird names, numbers etc AND automatically update XY location from the GPS ie a site AND see where i am in QGIS relative to other layers such as vegetation aerials etc.

status - at the moment QGIS easily logs a route and shows me where I am.

my question is - should i migrate access data to spatial database such as SpatiaLite or similar and then work on automatic logging of GPS data with a field entry

or write a macro/module in the access database to GET XY data from the GPS

Comment: So you want to create a new point feature where the GPS is?

Comment: Its unlikely you'll have enough (manual) observations to really need a spatial database. You could log them to a shapefile or any other vector format that is supported in QGIS. To me, this seems like you need a simplified UI, not a storage format - perhaps something like http://www.niwa.co.nz/software/quantum-map

Comment: Ive done some more reading/thinking and really all i need to do is create a form in access database with macro that reads the XY from the GPS. I need to learn how to do that now. im not sure this is the best place to ask - thanks @BradHards